# Boot Loader is not working, OS is not loading

Tags: boot, grub2, bios, bootloader

I have Windows 7 on Lenovo G580. I tried to install the latest version of Ubuntu but the installation failed while creating the BOOT Order. After that neither Windows7 nor Ubuntu is able to boot. Many times it **shows that System Boot Order is not found.**

Another time the Ubuntu screen loads and it keeps on flickering. I installed Ubuntu using pen drive.
Installation of Ubuntu did not complete. It showed some error.

I also tried to re-install Ubuntu. But the DVD is not booting. DVD drive is good.

I have forgotten the BIOS supervisor password. Hence I can not enter the  Master BIOS Set up.
How could I fix it ?
Regards
Rudra

Comment: `Installation of Ubuntu did not complete. It showed some error.`  Which error did it show? Please take a screenshot (with a mobile phone), and edit your question to mention the error. Without knowing the exact error we may not be able to help. Also, your Ubuntu iso may have become corrupt. See https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0

Comment: It shows the error the "System Boot Order is not found" below Appears a command prompt  which is inside grub>>. and  If I try to install through  DVD Drive a screen appears written UBUNTU and  it flickers and nothing happens.